# A series of measures

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of finite measures on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$. We put:

$$\mu(A):= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu_n(A)}{2^n(1+\mu_n(\Omega))}$$

Show that $\mu$ is a finite measure.

I have no idea how to even start the proof. Do I also need to show that $\mu$ is really a measure?

Comment: What if you were asked if this series converges where $a_n \geq b_n \geq 0$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2^n(1 + a_n)}$$

One of the reasons one to two years ago you had to answer questions like this one were so you could answers like yours.

Comment: Well... $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2^n(1 + a_n)} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2^n(1 + b_n)} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2^nb_n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}<\infty$.

Comment: Yes, you need to show this is a measure: check monotonicity and countable additivity.